# get data from request when creating object in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to verify email by sending a code, that's how i'm approaching the problem: I created a model named Email_for_Verification with two fields (email , code) the code is generated randomly, i create an instance of this model when the user enters his email, i send the generated code on email, in the second step, the user enters the received code, and i'm proceeding to the validation with a View named : Verify_code. but i'm encountring an error.
i'm facing this error when trying to send email to the user when creating the Email_for_Verification instance

```
'Request' object has no attribute 'email'
```

Here is my code

Views.py

```
class Verify_code(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        code = data.get('code')
        email = data.get('email')
        email_for_verification = models.Email_for_Verification.objects.get(email=email)
        if code == email_for_verification.code:
            return Response({"valid" : "Valid code", "email": email}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else :
            return Response({"invalid" : "Invalid code", "email": email}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        
class EmailForVerificationView(CreateAPIView):
       class EmailForVerificationView(CreateAPIView):
        queryset = models.Email_for_Verification.objects.all()
        serializer_class = EmailForVerificationSerializer
        def create(self, request):
                    created = models.Email_for_Verification.objects.create(email=request.data['email']).save()


                    email=created.get('email')
                    code = created.get('code')
                    send_mail(
                    'Here is the code of verification',
                    code,
                    'dummy@mail.com',
                    [email],
                    fail_silently=True,
                )
                    return Response({"code" : code, "email": email}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Models.py

```
def generate_activation_code():
    return int(''.join([str(random.randint(0,10)) for _ in range(6)]))

class Email_for_Verification(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=100, verbose_name='email', unique=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=6, default=generate_activation_code)
```

Serializers.py

```
class EmailForVerificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
            model = Email_for_Verification
            fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
created = models.Email_for_Verification.objects.create(email=request.email).save()
```

Should be:

```
created = models.Email_for_Verification.objects.create(email=request.data['email'])
```

The email field is sent in `request.data` no in `request`

Comment: i edited the code please take a look                                   i have the following error now                                           'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: remove `save()` from this line. it is unnecessary

Comment: also the same error : 'Email_for_Verification' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: The `Email_for_Verification` is a model instance, not a dict. use: `email=created.email` instead of `email=created.get('email')`, same for `code`